# sql where clause in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is my working sql syntax using sql query analyzer, it display the record i wanted

```
SELECT     OE_Category, OE_ID
FROM         tblOfficeEquipmentProfile
WHERE     (OE_ID = 'dxdxdx')
```

Upon using it to vb.net:

```
 Public Sub DisplayCategory()
    'based on oe_id'
    Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim sqlcommand As New SqlCommand

    sqlconn.Open()
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT OE_Category, OE_ID FROM tblOfficeEquipmentProfile WHERE OE_ID = '" & txtOEID.Text & "'", sqlconn)
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    da.Fill(dt)
    cmbCategory.DataSource = dt
    cmbCategory.ValueMember = "CAT_ID"
    cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "CAT_Name"
    sqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

An error occured:

> Could not bind to the new display member.

Comment: Watch out for that huge SQL injection you have: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648339.aspx please use parameters instead.

Answer (score 5):

Your selecting `OE_Category, OE_ID`  and binding `CAT_ID` and `CAT_Name`

try instead:

```
cmbCategory.ValueMember = "OE_ID"
cmbCategory.DisplayMember = "OE_Category"
```

You also dont bind the control

Comment: even if i take off CAT_Name. and change CAT_ID to the display or value member still not sir

Comment: call cmbCatefory.DataBind();

Comment: property access must assign to the property or use its value. its not available sir i use vb.net 2003

Comment: have you called databind on control?

Comment: yes sir, its not available in vb.net 2003 cmbCategory.DataBindings() returns error saying property access must assign to the property or use its value

Comment: In that case DataBind is not required, the code should work. Chnage the field names you are binding too as instructed and tell mewhat happens please.

Comment: already tried changing, exchanging field names still the same